# Reading a file and writing to cmd window using mutators/accessors

Tags: java, arrays, accessor, mutators

I'm working on a project for school and seem to have dug myself into a rabbit hole.  I need to read a file consisting of just positive and negative numbers from a file and display them to a command window along with the date.  I was able to get the end result but cannot list the marginal results. Thanks in advance!

```
    class Account{

    private int id = 0; //private int data field named id for the account (default 0).
    private double balance = 0.0; //private double data field named balance for the account (default 0)
    private static double annualInterestRate = 0.0; //private double data field named annualInterestRate that stores the current interest rate (default 0). Assume all accounts have the same interest rate.

    private java.util.Date dateCreated; //private Date data field named dateCreated that stores the date when the account was created.

        //=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
        public Account() { //no-arg constructor that creates a default account.

        dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
    }
    //=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
    public Account(int id, double balance) { //constructor that creates an account with the specified id and initial balance.
        this();
        this.id = id;
        this.balance = balance;
    }
    //=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
    public int getId() {//accessor and mutator methods for id, balance, and annualInterestRate.

        return this.id;
    }
    //=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
    public double getBalance() {//accessor and mutator methods for id, balance, and annualInterestRate.
        return this.balance;
    }
    //=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
    public double getAnnualInterestRate() {//accessor and mutator methods for id, balance, and annualInterestRate.
        return annualInterestRate;
    }
    //=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
    public String getDateCreated() {//accessor method for dateCreated
        return this.dateCreated.toString();
    }
    //=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
    public void setId(int id) { //mutator for id
        this.id = id;
    }
    //=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
    public void setBalance(double balance) { //mutator for balance
        this.balance = balance;
    }
    //=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
    public void setAnnualInterestRate(double annualInterestRate) { //mutator annual interest rate
        this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
    }
    //=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
    public double getMonthlyInterestRate() { //method named getMonthlyInterestRate() that returns the monthly interest rate.
        return (annualInterestRate / 100) / 12 ;
    }
    //=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
    public double getMonthlyInterest() { //method named getMonthlyInterest() that returns the monthly interest.
        return balance * getMonthlyInterestRate();
    }
   //=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
    public void withdraw(double amount) { //method named withdraw that withdraws a specified amount from the account.
        this.balance -= amount;
    }
    //=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
    public void deposit(double amount) { //method named deposit that deposits a specified amount to the account.

        this.balance += amount;
    }
     //=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
}//end class account
```

I'm pretty sure that class is OK. It's the one with the main method that I need the most help or guidance with.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class AccountHomework{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{

    File fn = new File("transactions.txt");
    Scanner dataIn = new Scanner(fn);

        Account account = new Account(1122, 20000);

        double[] transactions = new double[10];
        account.setAnnualInterestRate(4.5);
        account.withdraw(2500.0);
        account.deposit(3000.0);

printMethod(account);
}

public static void printMethod(Account acct){
        System.out.printf(" %8s    %17s    %13s","Balance","Monthly Interest","Date Created\n");
        System.out.printf(" $%6.2f        $%6.2f            %s\n",acct.getBalance(),acct.getMonthlyInterest(),acct.getDateCreated());

    }

public static void fillTransactions(Scanner dataIn, Stock[] stocks){

     double transactions;

 for(int indx = 0; indx<stocks.length;indx++){
     transactions = dataIn.nextDouble();
     dataIn.nextLine();  // read the extra carriage return
     if (transactions < 0)
        dataIn.withdraw();
        else
        dataIn.deposit();

     account[indx] = new Account();
     account[indx].populateStockData(transactions);

     }//end for
}//end fillStockArray
}
```

Comment: "...cannot list the marginal results": what does this mean?

Comment: You've defined `fillTransactions` method but you've used it nowhere.

Comment: Scott Hunter meanting that I can't list every transation in detail, only the end result.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed 2 things:
1. the scanner dataIn is not used to read the data, I see you have a method fillTransaction, but its not called from main
2. Within fillTransactions you are using the methods withdraw() and deposit() on the scanner, when the methods are actually defined on the class Account

Comment: That's test data.  I'm trying to use the deposit/withdraw methods in a loop with the condition that the double is <0 or > 0.